# How to get my text to display over video (React)

Tags: reactjs, video, text, overlay, inline-styles

I'm trying to add Text over a video that takes up 100 vh/vw, and it's about halfway down my page. I can't seem to find a good way to use Inline Styles to put the text over the video.

I tried top: "0" but that just brings it to the top of the entire webpage, not the top of the div that it's in.

Does anyone have any tips? Here is my code!

```
function About() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className="parallaxImg"
        style={{
          backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
          backgroundImage: "url(" + Beach + ")",
          display: "flex",
          objectFit: "cover",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          width: "100%",
          height: "30vh",
          zIndex: "1",
          opacity: "80%",
          backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        }}
      >
        <div class="center">
          <h1
            style={{
              opacity: "100%",
              color: "white",
            }}
          >
            About{" "}
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br/>
      
//The video starts here. Above was just a parallax header thing.

      <div>
          <video
            loop
            autoPlay
            muted
            id="video"
            style={{
              height: "100vh",
              width: "100vw",
              objectFit: "cover",
              position: "relative",
              pointerEvents: "none",
            }}
          >
            <source src={Video} type="video/mp4" />
          </video>
          <div
            style={{
              color: "green",
              position: "absolute",
              textAlign: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
              
            }}
          >
            <p>
              Aloha, I’m a front-end developer located on the island of Oahu, Hawaii. I have a serious passion for technology and learning all the things to make technology work for me.
            </p>
            <p>
              When i’m not tinkering with the latest gadget, you can find me surfing Hawaii's waves, on a beach volleyball court or vacationing at a ski resort breaking another collar bone.
            </p>
            <p>
              Other than sports and technology, I am very much a family person and faith oriented. Both keep me grounded and make me want to be the best version of myself.
            </p>
            <p>
              Overall, im trying to meet like-minded people who can mentor me to make me a stronger Web Developer, a smarter employee and a more wholesome and selfless person in general.
            </p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Here is a screen shot of what I'm seeing.(had to crop out most of the picture because it was too big of a file) [image: Screenshot of the lower half of the video and the next section.]

Here is my Github if it helps.

https://github.com/Shaneeyb/Portfolio-Project-3

Comment: If you give `position: relative`, to the `<div>` that wraps the `<video>` and the other `div`, then `top: 0` should work as expected on other `div`.

Comment: This totally worked!! Thank you so much!